# How to find loan term given monthly interest rate, monthly payment and principal

Tags: javascript, node.js, while-loop

Here's my JS function to calculate loan term which works, however when I put a value for the interestRate higher than 6, it creates an infinite loop. Please help

```
export const calculateLoanTerm = (amount, interestRate, monthlyPayment) => {
  
  const monthlyInterestRate = interestRate / 100;
  let balance = amount;
  let term = 0;

  while (balance > 0) {
    const interest = balance * monthlyInterestRate;
    const payment = Math.min(monthlyPayment, balance + interest);
    balance -= payment - interest;
    term++;

    if (balance <= 0) break;
  }
  return term;
};
```

How can I restructure and avoid the loop?

Use test values;

```
interestRate = 7 // If you use 6 it works
monthlyPayment = 4,500,000
amount = 65,000,000
```

Comment: It's an infinite loop because the interest is higher than the monthly payment (7% of 65 million is 4,550,000) so the balance keeps increasing indefinitely. You'll have to add a check for that and decide what should happen in that case.

Comment: Shouldn't the `amount` be increased by 7% **only once** instead of monthly? You take a 65M load with 7% interests -> you have to pay back 69.55M. You don't even need a loop then, `term = (amount + amount * interestRate / 100) / monthlyPayment;`

Comment: @Cid That would be a fee instead of interest. Interest accrues continuously until the debt is paid off. 7% monthly interest is pretty brutal though – that's the equivalent of 125% yearly interest.

Comment: @GuyIncognito no wonder why I hate banks...

Comment: @Cid I'm about to quit this one. Bank math is weird.

Comment: I made few searches and the interest is yearly and the amount is re-evaluated monthly, so in your loop, you should have `const interest = balance * (interestRate / 100) / 12;`

Comment: @Cid The math isn't correct. A monthly interest rate of 7/12 won't result in a yearly interest rate of 7. (1 + 0.07/12) ** 12 = 1,0722900808562. That's > 7.22%